# In react.js ,why always throw ' setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component...... error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the following code, on `componentWillUnmount` I remove the scroll event listener but the dev-tool always throws the following error:

> setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the undefined component.

#### The code:

```
render () {
    let opa=!this.state.opa?
        {
            backgroundColor:'#fff',
            borderBottom:'.01rem solid #e8e8e8'
        }:null;
    return (
        <div id='search' style={opa}>
            <input type='text' placeholder=''/>
            <div id='ser_scan'></div>
        </div>
    )
}

toggle_opa () {
    let opa;
    let _top=~~(document.body.scrollTop*100/parseInt(document.documentElement.style.fontSize,10))
    opa=_top>=215?false:true;
    console.log(1)
    this.setState({opa})
}

componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('scroll',this.toggle_opa.bind(this));
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log(1231)
    document.removeEventListener('scroll',this.toggle_opa)
}
```

what is wrong?

Comment: I believe the variable opa which ur using for setState inside toggle_opa is not an object. Also are u sure, you initiate the state before using setState

Comment: have you tried. document.removeEventListener('scroll',this.toggle_opa.bind(this)). Error is because component is not unmounted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your eventlistener is never properly removed, so I guess you get the error when you scroll after the component has unmounted.

First, make sure `toggle_opa` is always bound to `this` by adding a constructor function inside the component

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.toggle_opa = this.toggle_opa.bind(this);
}
```

then you can add and remove eventlisteners like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('scroll',this.toggle_opa);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log(1231)
    document.removeEventListener('scroll',this.toggle_opa)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer , This problem has been solved . thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you are using the bind method. It curries a new function, so the handler you add in didMount is different than the one you send to removeListener. You can use arrow function while defining the handler, like this -
`toggle_opa =()=>{......}`
Then simply pass toggle_opa to the add/remove Listener calls. No need for bind.